ESP32-C6 USB CDC code upload does not work with example sketches
I wanted to try out the ESP32-C6-Mini chips, so I built a breakout board for it. Below, you can see a picture of my setup.

As you can see, I wanted to skip a USB-TTL-adapter and tried the USB CDC mode. After some time, I was able to upload a very simple sketch to the chip, and it worked as intended. This is the code I tried:
int i = 0;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  Serial.println(i);
  i = i+1;
  delay(1000);
} 

As I said, this works without a problem, and I can see the result in the serial monitor.
However if I try to upload a more complex example sketch I can not see a single log. I tried the WifiScan example sketch and it seems to upload just fine but I can not see prints in the serial monitor. Do you have a idea what could be the problem?
Here is a screenshot of the settings I used:

So I think the sketch works but the printing to the serial monitor does not. Is there something wrong with my setup?
EDIT
Sometimes the Serial Monitor will say: ESP-ROM:esp32c6-20220919
